# Can CMakeList.txt specify dependencies that will be installed before compiling the source?

Tags: cmake

Can CMakeList.txt specify dependencies of a project that will be installed before compiling the source?

My project depends on a third-party library L. I would like have CMake to enforce that L be installed properly before compiling the project.

I noticed that there is an install command on the CMake website: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html, but it seems to be about how to install the project itself.

I am new to CMake.

Comment: **Example** of your intention would be very helpful for understanding your needs.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear: Do you want CMake to install a third-party library or application before generating a buildsystem for your project? The `install` command is typically for installing *your* project and its dependencies after your source is compiled and the build completes. Can you provide a simple example to better illustrate what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks. A small example is provided above. See my edits.

Comment: "I would like have CMake to **enforce** that L be installed properly" - If by "to enforce" you mean "to check", then use `find_library` for check library's existence. If you want not "to check", but "to install", then use `execute_process` or `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target` with appropriate COMMAND options.

Answer (score 0):

CMake can not install downloaded binary packages of external dependencies for you. The only thing CMake can do is to fail in the generate step when the required library can not be found by using [`find_package(... REQUIRED ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html). 
To automatically retrieving dependencies you have to use a package manager. The most relevant three for C++ are

- [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg)
- [conan](https://conan.io/)
- [hunter](https://github.com/cpp-pm/hunter)

I currently use hunter, but the main developer just retiered from the project and it is not yet clear how active further development will be.